# Printing the second page from a Calc sheet

Tags: pdf, export, libreoffice-calc

I've created a simple invoice document in LibreOffice Calc and it consists of 2 pages. I have defined the print range for my document as:

```
$A$1:$D$33,$D$34:$D$35
```

My first page holds the actual invoice information the second page is a single merged cell holding terms and conditions text (wrapped to the cell width). The second page is defined by a row break.

When I export the sheet as a PDF the first page comes out great but the second page with the terms text is all wrong. On the left hand side I see a portion of text (looks like a single column) and when I select the text inside the PDF I can see it go of the page somewhere to the left. I get the same result in a print preview.

I'm at a complete loss on how to approach this problem and any insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem by moving my Terms & Conditions text to the right of my invoice print area and then redefine the print area for the T&C's. Oddly this worked. It seems there is some reason why Calc wasn't able to print a second print area defined below the first one but is able to print the second page when it's positioned to the right of it.

Answer (score 1):

From the LibreOffice help (*formulae, printing, instead of results*) - not sure if you can mix printing on one sheet so you may have to move the formulae to a second sheet.

> **Printing Sheet Details** When printing a sheet you can select which details are to be printed: Row and column headers Sheet grid Comments
>   Objects and graphics Charts Drawing objects
>   **Formulae** To choose the details proceed as follows:
>   1. Select the sheet you want to print.
>   2. Choose Format - Page. The command is not visible if the sheet was opened with write protection on. In that case, click the Edit File
>   icon on the Standard Bar.
>   3. Select the Sheet tab. In the Print area mark the details to be printed and click OK.
>   4. Print the document.